# Changes to the database are displayed only after restarting gunicorn

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

The data obtained in the `NextPredictionListView` in the `prediction_next_list.html` template is updated immediately. And in `LastPredictionsListView` (`prediction_last_list.html`) only after restarting `gunicorn`.

```
class NextPredictionsListView(ListView):
    model = Prediction
    queryset = Prediction.objects.filter(prediction_result=None)
    template_name = 'app/prediction_next_list.html'


class LastPredictionsListView(ListView):
    queryset = Prediction.objects.filter(~Q(prediction_result=None), date__lt=datetime.now())
    template_name = 'app/prediction_last_list.html'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the queryset itself is lazy, the evaluation of `datetime.now()` isn't; that will be set at the time the class is first imported. So, you won't ever see any results with a date after that time.

For anything dynamic like this, you should move it out of class level and into a method, in this case the `get_queryset` method:

```
class LastPredictionsListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'app/prediction_last_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Prediction.objects.filter(~Q(prediction_result=None), date__lt=datetime.now())
```